# use dynamic url and image in same imageView

Tags: android, image, url, dynamic, view

I have an imageView in my  layout name is iv1

I wanna when user offline it will show an image and link with a default url.
But when user get online i wanna get the image from url and the image link with dynamic url.

How can do it, any good practice..please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a different class named as `ConnectionDetector`

```
   public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context context ;
    WifiManager wifiManager ;
    static WifiInfo wifiInfo ;

    public final static String internetError = "No Internet Connection";

    public ConnectionDetector (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context ;
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    }

    public boolean isInternetConnected()
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if(connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length ; i++)
                {
                    if(info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Now from your activity do the following,

```
ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector (getApplicationContext());
boolean isConnected = cd.isInternetConnected();

if (isConnected)
{
    // Internet is present, here you can download the image from URL and set it to ImageView. If you're new to image downloading then better use picasso library. It's only 1 line of code. 
}

else
{
    // No internet connection, you can display default image and url in your imageview
}
```